# Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser + selenium + robotframework

Tags: selenium2, robotframework

I'm using robotframework+seleniumlibrary and I often got the following error when I launch test cases

```
Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser
```

I'm connected by "ssh -X nome@server-ip" on my company server from where I launch TC, and after I got the error above, the only way to solve it, it is to disconnect and re-start a new ssh connection....

is there any other way to solve it?

I'm using firefox 16 as browser for my test case. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't determine why the browser won't launch, you can make your tests more robust.  Make sure to clean the environment during test warmup, add some retry/wait/timeout wrappers around the section that launches the browser, and kill any processes and services that aren't relevant to the test.

In order to find out why the browser is crashing, you can look into the differences between failed and successful scenarios, but it might be more helpful to put in some debugging and logging code or look at event log data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer here which might help: [Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/selenium-users/nFhusJoAzV8).

I know that I have had issues with firefox driver not killing the firefox process when it was finished and had to add code to kill all firefox processes as part of the cleanup of my tests.